# Allowed to change sign in quadratic exponent diffusion probability for solving integral identity?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Given the probability of finding a particle between $x$ and $x+dx$ with constants $4D$ put to $1$:
$$
w(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-x^2/t}.
$$

Prove
$$
w(x-x_0,t-t_0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty w(x-x',t-t')w(x'-x_0,t'-t_0)dx'.
$$

Also I have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a(x-z)^2-b(x-y)^2} dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a+b}}e^{-\frac{ab}{a+b}(y-z)^2}.
$$

The math seems to check out if I change sign inside the exponent: $w(x-x_0,t-t_0)=w(x_0-x,t-t_0)$. It doesn't seem to matter for $w$, as the exponent in $w$ is quadratic anyway. Is it allowed in this proof?

Comment: It is allowed. $\phantom{.}$

Comment: $w(x,t)$ only contains the term $x^2$ dependent on $x$, therefore $w(x,t)=w(-x,t)$ and you don't even need to change the sign in the exponent. The last identity you wrote is correct, so if you have proven one of them, you have also proven the other.